# Access to global variables modified in a function from different files

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, export

I am using webpack and I have 2 global variables, I assign them in a function and I want to use them in another function in another file. Is that possible?
my code:

```
var info = [];
async function getSearch(searchBar) {
       try {
           const value = (document.getElementById(searchBar).value).toLowerCase();
           const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value}&APPID=1&units=metric`;
           const url2 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value}&APPID=1&units=imperial`;
           const response = await fetch(url, { mode: 'cors' });
           const response2 = await fetch(url2, { mode: 'cors' });
           cityData = await response.json();
           cityData2 = await response2.json();
           info = [cityData, cityData2];
       } catch (error) {
           console.error('Error:', error);
       }
   };

function getInfo(){
 return info;
}
```

I export both variables (cityData and cityData2) to use them into another function in another file but got the error 'variable not defined'. How can I do to access the data wherever I want?
Thanks

Comment: Your function is **asynchronous**.  The variables will not be assigned values until the asynchronous operations complete.

Comment: @Pointy: Your comment is legit, but OP is reporting `variable not defined`. Looks like they have a problem other than what you mentioned.

Comment: If I console.log the variables after assignment, I get the data, but if I try to export to another file I get the ```variable not defined```

Comment: @RahulBhobe "variable not defined" could mean an error due to the variables being `undefined`, which they will be until the async operations complete. They appear to be objects, so something like `cityData.name` would trigger a "Cannot access property "name" of undefined`

Comment: @JavierCorreas - The export happens before the values are assigned. So the behavior you see is not a surprise. You could instead export functions and have the functions return these values.

Comment: I have added the values to a new variable and created a function to get that array back wherever I want, but still does not work. With a console.log I can see that the array 'info' get the data.